# Hokkaido night trains after Shinkansen introduction

Tags: trains, japan, hokkaido

In march 2016 the Shinkansen will [link](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2018_hokkaido.html) Honshu to Shin-Hakodate. According to JP Rail's [website](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/routemaps/cassiopeia_hokutosei.html) the Hokutosei is already discontinued and [Japan Guide](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2356.html) says the overnight Cassiopeia and Hamanasu services will be discontinued in 2016.

If [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkaido_Shinkansen#/media/File:Tokyosapporotrainchart.png) chart from Wiki is to be believed the journey will still take around 7+ hours to Sapporo from Tokyo.

Are there any plans to maintain any overnight train service to Hokkaido beyond march 2016 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, there are no plans to retain sleeper service to Hokkaido.

Overnight trains of any kind are very much an endangered species in Japan: [here's the full list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_passenger_trains_of_Japan#Night_trains).  Once *Cassiopeia* and *Hamanasu* get the ax there will only be **two (2) regular services left in the entire country**, namely the *Sunrise Izumo* and *Sunrise Seto* services from Tokyo to Izumo and Takamatsu respectively.  There are also a few irregular services that operate only during high season though, plus the odd superluxury cruiser like [*Seven Stars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Stars_in_Kyushu).

Comment: Is this just a conclusion based on the current trend or did JR make it public ?

Comment: The cancellation of Cassiopeia and Hamanasu is public.  There are no other sleepers to Hokkaido left, nor any plans that I know of to introduce any.  It's hard to prove a negative, but this is about as good as it gets...